# Solace Spring Cloud Stream Binding

Tags: kerberos, spring-cloud-stream, solace

How do you initialize a Solace Binder with Spring Cloud Stream where the connection AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME is AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_GSS_KRB?

solace:
  java:
    host: tcp://.....
    msgVpn: myvpn
    client-username: username
    apiProperties:
      AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME: AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_GSS_KRB
      KRB_SERVICE_NAME: HOST
      JaasLoginContext: SolaceGSS

Error Response (403) - No matching configured Authorization Group was found

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the Client Authorization is failing. Client Authorization is different from Client Authentication.

Once a client connection to a Message VPN is successfully **authenticated**, access to the event broker resources and messaging capabilities within that Message VPN must be **authorized** for the client.

The default authorization method is Internal. It looks like you have set LDAP as the authorization method but there is no matching LDAP group for your client.

You can refer to the Solace documentation for more information on configuring LDAP Authorization.